Routing is not working properly for Angular project
When i go to the gif page it's not displayes gifs, When i go to the for ex: /upload, it shows me error message "cannot match any routes. URL segment: "upload"
// app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { GifComponent } from '../gif/gif.component';
import { GifDetailComponent } from '../gif/gif-detail.component'; // Import GifDetailComponent
import { UploadComponent } from '../Upload/upload.component'; // Import UploadComponent

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'gifs/:title', component: GifComponent },
  { path: 'gifs/category/:category', component: GifComponent },
  { path: 'upload', component: UploadComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

<!-- app.component.html -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="categories">
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let category of categories">{{ category }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="gifs">
    <h1 class="title">Gifs</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let gif of gifs">
      <h2 class="title">
        <a [routerLink]="['/gifs', gif.title]" (click)="redirectToGif(gif)">{{ gif.title }}</a>
      </h2>
      <img class="gif" [src]="gif.src" alt="{{ gif.title }}" (click)="redirectToGif(gif)">
      <a [routerLink]="['/gifs', gif.title]">View Gif</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

// app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RootComponent } from './root.component'; // Import RootComponent
import { GifDetailComponent } from '../gif/gif-detail.component'; // Import GifDetailComponent
import { UploadComponent } from '../Upload/upload.component'; // Import UploadComponent
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RootComponent, // Declare RootComponent
    GifDetailComponent,
    UploadComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ RootComponent ] // Bootstrap RootComponent
})
export class AppModule { }

There is my github : https://github.com/BekaEn/GifApp/blob/GifApp/
I think there can be a only one mistake somewhere and i can't find it. spent many hours to find it but nothing. I hope some1 can find a answer

I looked at your GitHub, you define routes two times, one in AppRoutingModule and one in app.route.ts which export an empty array. Try to move your routes in app.route.ts and only define the routes once.
